# Deadlock in simple MPI pipelined ring broadcast code

Tags: c, mpi, deadlock, broadcast, pipeline

I'm learning MPI code. I am trying to do a pipelined ring broadcast using different sized chunks. However, when I run my code, it reaches a deadlock while Process 0 attempts to send the second chunk of data, and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: this is part of a much larger code. It fills a buffer with chars on Process 0. After some simple debugging using print statements, I believe there is something wrong with line 9 (marked with an ***) because that's where the program stalls. The second chunk of data is never sent from Process 0.

```
int offset;
MPI_Status status;

if (rank == 0) {
    offset = 0;
    while (offset < NUM_BYTES) {
        MPI_Send(&chunk_size, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&buffer[offset], chunk_size, MPI_BYTE, rank + 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD); ***
        offset = offset + chunk_size;
        if ((offset + chunk_size) >= NUM_BYTES) {
            chunk_size = (NUM_BYTES - offset);
        }
    }
}
else {
    MPI_Recv(&chunk_size, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, rank - 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&buffer[offset], chunk_size, MPI_BYTE, rank - 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    if (rank != num_procs - 1) {
        MPI_Send(&chunk_size, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, rank + 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&buffer[offset], chunk_size, MPI_BYTE, rank + 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a remark: as MPI preserves the chronological order of messages with the same tag sent between two processes within a given communicator, you don't actually need to send the offset. Simply keep a counter and increment it each time with the amount of data received. Also, sending the chunk size is redundant as you could simply use `MPI_Probe` to probe for a message and `MPI_Get_count` to get the number of elements in the [probed] message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine (although not very effective since all communications are serialised) but you have a big miss: only process #0 communicates in a loop so it will send several times whereas all other processes will expect only one single set of communications. Add the same `while` loop in the `else` part, and that should work.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix my problem by adding the while loop that you suggested as well as adjusting it to check if ((offset + chunk_size) < NUM_BYTES) rather than (offset < NUM_BYTES) since a non-master will never receive an offset greater than NUM_BYTES.